# SwiftUI List and Lazy loading

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've created a simple SwiftUI application, which is displaying images from the network in the list. All images are loaded in the background. At this point, all work as expected. However, if during the load, some State variable did trigger, all my cells get re-initialized.

Let's see the code:

```
struct ImageView: View {

   @ObservedObject var imageLoader = ImageLoader()

   var body: some View {

        VStack {

            if self.imageLoader.isLoaded {

               DisplayImage(self.imageLoader.image)
            } else {

               Text("Loading...")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {

            self.imageLoader.loadImage()
        }
   }
}

struct TableView: View {
   
   @State var someTrigger: Bool = false;

    var body: some View {

       List {

           ForEach( someCollection, id: \.self) {

              ImageView()
           }
       }
    }
}
```

So, if 'someTrigger' is triggered while images are loading, all the cells will be re-initialized, imageLoader will be re-initialzed, .onAppear will not be called, the image won't load.

Is this expected behaviour? In that case, I just can't initialize my model with some background tasks that way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**SwiftUI 2.0**

Use instead `StateObject` wrapper, it will allow not recreate loader

```
struct ImageView: View {
   @StateObject var imageLoader = ImageLoader()
```

**SwiftUI 1.0**

Possible solution (might depend on your real code) is to make `ImageView` equatable by some property (eg, `id` only) explicitly, ie. excluding `imageLoader` itself. This can give chance for rendering engine to not replace `ImageView` on state change

For example

```
struct ImageView: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.url == rhs.url
    }

    let url: URL // some unique property
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader = ImageLoader()

    // ... other code
}
```

and use

```
   ForEach( someCollection, id: \.self) {
      ImageView().equatable()       // << here !!
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be solved for you by passing in the `imageLoader` rather than having it initialized in the view itself. I would actually recommend having the collection objects have an `ImageLoader` which updates some `@Published` image property. Try to set up the model to do all the heavy lifting and let the view just declare what it should be for each state of your model.